# Nested dictionairy issue

Tags: python

I have a function that gathers data from a model like this

```
def get_unit_data(self, unit):
    unit_data_dict = {
        'bank_1_bus_voltage': self.model.unit_dict[unit].bank_dict[1].bus_voltage,
        'bank_1_battery_voltages': self.model.unit_dict[unit].bank_dict[1].battery_voltage_dict,
    }
    return unit_data_dict
```

In short, it returns this after the first iteration

```
{
    'bank_1_bus_voltage': 0.0, 
    'bank_1_battery_voltages': {
        1: {
            'voltage_start': 0.0, 
            'voltage_end': 0.0
        }
    }
}
```

Somewhere else is a function that calls this one, modifies it a little and passes it on to some website for visualization

```
def get(self):
    unit = request.args.get('unit')
    unit_data = self.parent.controller.get_unit_data(int(unit))

    unit_data['bank_1_bus_voltage'] = str(unit_data['bank_1_bus_voltage']) + "V"
    unit_data['bank_1_battery_voltages'][1]['voltage_start'] = str(unit_data['bank_1_battery_voltages'][1]['voltage_start']) + "V"

    return unit_data
```

After a few iterations the `get_unit_data` output looks like this

```
{
    'bank_1_bus_voltage': 0.0, 
    'bank_1_battery_voltages': {
        1: {
            'voltage_start': '0.0VVVVV', 
            'voltage_end': 0.0
        }
    }
}
```

How come this final `get` function leaves the `bank_1_bus_voltage` as it is, but messes up the `voltage_start`?

Comment: The outer modified value is newly created every time you call `get_unit_data`. With the nested value however, you modify a dict that is also referenced by some `self.model.unit_dict[unit].bank_dict[1].battery_voltage_dict`, so here the changed value will be picked up with every call to  `get_unit_data`.

Comment: I created a function to gather the dict in a different way, but it seems a kinda cumbersome this way. Anyways it fixed my problem, so thanks a lot!

Comment: You could just use `copy.deepcopy(self.model.unit_dict[unit].bank_dict[1].battery_voltage_dict)` in your `get_unit_data`.

Answer (score 0):

Modified get_unit_data into

```
def get_unit_data(self, unit):
    unit_data_dict = {
        'bank_1_bus_voltage': self.model.unit_dict[unit].bank_dict[1].bus_voltage,
        'bank_1_battery_voltages': copy.deepcopy(self.model.unit_dict[unit].bank_dict[1].battery_voltage_dict),
    }
    return unit_data_dict
```

Credits to @schwobaseggl